# How can I use a CVX variable in a Numpy product that is to be Minimized?

Tags: optimization, gurobi, cvxpy, cvxopt

I'm trying to optimize a configuration X (boolean), such that the total price : base_price + discount, on a configuration is minimized, but the problem formulation gives a Matmul error since x is a cvxpy Variable and thus doesn't conform to the Numpy shape even though it was defined with the correct length.

```py
n = len(Configuration)
x = cp.Variable(n, boolean=True)
problem = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(base_price + price@(price_rules_A@x <= price_rules_B)), [
        config_rules_A@x <= config_rules_B, 
        config_rules_2A@x == config_rules_2B
    ])
# where price@(price_rules_A@x <= price_rules_B) is the total discount 
# and price, price_rules_A and price_rules_B are numpy arrays
```

The error i get is

```py
ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 does not have enough dimensions (has 0, gufunc core with signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) requires 1)
```

I expect it to find an optimal config for x ( 0010110...) such that the discount is minimized but it doesn't. Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: This part looks problematic: `price@(price_rules_A@x <= price_rules_B)`, is that what you intended. Is it convex?

Comment: Yes, that was intended. The inequality should produce a boolean numpy array which is to be multiplied with the price array to get the total discount which is to be maximized/minimized. Do you know an alternative way to do this in CVX?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible, but here's an idea: `cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(p@x), [A@x<=B])`. I pushed the inequality to the constraints, because it _is_ a convex set (if you relax `x` to be real valued.

Comment: @user6714507, try changing the shape of `x` to `(n, 1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the evaluation of the inequality in the objective function is suppose to work as index to `price`, you can rewrite the function as

```
cp.Minimize(base_price + price@(1-(price_rules_B - price_rules_A@x))
```

Then the elements in price where the inequality is true will be summed.